# Use Azure Active Directory as a single sign on service for multiple web applications

Tags: active-directory, azure

Can we use Azure Active Directory as a single sign on service for multiple web applications that support LDAP authentication, but does not support Azure active directory?
Usually such applications require to set ldap server, connecting user/password  and base dn.

I did a search for these parameters over my account, but failed to find anything relevant.

So I am in a doubt about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Active Directory does not support LDAP, it is a modern auth provider using thinks like OpenID, SAML etc. In its default setup it will not be able to support applications that require LDAP.

You could look at Azure AD Domain Services which is an extension to Azure AD that provides traditional domain controllers as a service, which supports LDAP, however it has a number of limitations.